# How to evict persistent "Stream Blocks" in Spark completely

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, streaming, rdd

– update — we found that below situation occurs when we encounter
"com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions.ShutdownException: Can't update checkpoint - instance doesn't hold the lease for this shard"
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/issues/108
we use s3 directory (and dynamodb) to store checkpoints, but if such occurs blocks should not get stuck but continue to be evicted gracefully from memory, obviously kinesis library race condition is a problem onto itself...

Ran to a problem (also submitted spark jira task on the subject below) where "block streams" (some not all) are persisting leading at to the OOM

App is a standard kinesis/spark streaming app written in java (spark version is 2.0.2)

run starts initially well and automated SparkCleaner does its job nicely recycling streaming jobs (verified by looking at the Storage tab in admin)

then after some time some blocks get stuck in memory such as this block on one of the executor nodes

input-0-1485362233945   1   ip-<>:34245 Memory Serialized   1442.5 KB

after more time more blocks are getting stuck and never freed up

It is my understanding that the SparkContext cleaner will trigger removal or older blocks as well as trigger System.gc at the given interval which is 30 minutes by default

thanks on any feedback on this as this issue here prevents 100% uptime of the application

If this could be of value we use StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER()

[Spark Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19364)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to perform the eviction manually:

1. get KinesisInputDStream.generatedRDDs (using reflection)
2. for each generatedRDDs (it should contains BlockRDD) perform something like DStream.clearMetadata.

I already used a similar hack for mapWithState and for other Spark things that use memory for nothing.